# ActiveAdmin - Customize scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a Member table with a `verified` boolean flag, and I have a scope that displays all the entries where `verified` is false, as follows:

```
scope :not_verified do |members|
  members.where(:verified => false)
end
```

However, I want my scope to also include entries where `verified` is null. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scope :not_verified do |members|
    members.where('verified = ? OR verified IS NULL', false)
end
```